# How to remove sticker from car windshield without tearing it

Tags: car, glass, adhesive

How to remove a sticker from the inside of a car windshield which I want to leave undamaged so that it can be used on another car. The stickers are for car insurance, road tax (vignette) or other similar.

Lets say if they were applied on the wrong place or the wrong car and I want to move them, then I need to take them without damaging.

[image: stickers]

Comment: It should be noted that moving such stickers between vehicles *might* be illegal. Proceed with caution!

Comment: Many stickers are printed on thin vinyl plastic that "sticks" to glass with surface tension and can be lifted off without damage. Are you sure they are glued to the glass?

Answer (score 7):

If it is a plastic sticker, try to heat up the window from the other side of the sticker so it becomes somewhat loose, then you can gently peel it off and it should come right off.

However, if it is a paper based sticker you will not have much luck since those are really fragile. If you want to clean your window completely (ruining the stickers) I would suggest using a screen cleaner foam and a razor. Soak the sticker with the foam and without applying too much pressure on the windshield (don't scratch it) use a razor blade to peel it off.

Comment: any brand recommendations for the _screen cleaner foam_? (available in turkish market if possible)

Comment: @şaloma Sorry, I got the foam from my Car Service in the US, so can't be much of help.

Answer (score 5):

This process has worked well for me:

1. Heat the sticker with a hot air dryer to loosen the adhesive.
2. Insert the tip of a razor blade under one corner of the sticker.
3. Work the blade behind the sticker about 1/4 inch.
4. Press the loosened portion of the sticker against the flat side of the blade, then lift the blade and sticker together (slowly). If the sticker starts to tear, reheat and start another corner.
5. Use Goof Off, acetone, or another solvent to remove residue from glass.
6. Use contact adhesive if needed to improve adhesion to the new surface.

The warmer and softer the adhesive, the better the end result.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of success with hairspray and a razorblade. Simply spray the hairspray on the sticker, let it sit for ~5 minutes to dry somewhat, then use the razorblade to scrape off the sticker, starting with the corners if possible. As I understand it, the hairspray creates a bond on the sticker so that it doesn't break up into pieces as much. If there is any residue left, I'd use Goo Gone ([Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006IBNJ)) on it and it cleans up the adhesive very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

the type of adhesion differs from manufacturer to manufacturer.

some of them can be removed with heat(be carefull or it will change colors and shape)

some get losen with cleaning-alcohol(or hairspray wich usually is alcohol)

the best way would be to stick them to sellotape, or somthing, before stick it to the window

Answer (score 0):

1. Pour a very small amount of gasoline on rag
2. Rub the rag lightly and carefully on the sticker (I would suggest with your car door open)
3. Use another rag or something else to rub the sticker off.
4. Most should come off, and if it doesn't, repeat.
5. If that doesn't work, apply flame to gasoline

Comment: It's not about *removing* the sticker, but about *keeping it intact while doing so*.

Answer (score 0):

WD-40 (or any other multipurpose lubricant) will help dissolve the bonds. Lift the corner and spray a small amount directly on the point of contact and continue as you peel.

Then use a spray adhesive on the sticker to bond to the new surface.

Comment: WD40 will also destroy any printing on the paper, so it won't be undamaged.

Answer (score 0):

Shaving cream!!! I have been inspecting my own vehicles this way since the 70's. Be generous with the shaving cream and plan on taking a few hours if the sticker is glued well. I usually put the shaving cream on all over the sticker about and inch thick. After about an hour I come back and loosen all the edges. I remove the old shavig cream and re-apply more shaving cream. Repeat for as long as necessary. It cannot be stressed enough, this is going to take time but it works every time! I like it to be warm but I avoid direct sunlight because that seems to evaporate the active ingredient in the shaving cream. Usually after I put the first application of shaving cream on the window I take the shavig cream back into the house and use it to actually shave since I need to kill some time anyway. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before you apply your sticker to your windshield, stick it on your pants.
It will make the adhesive a lot less sticky so it will hold to the windshield but you can easily pull it off later.